# change div color with textbox

Tags: javascript, html, editbox

I am trying to make a small javascript program in which I have a Div that is transparent initially, and contains an editbox inside. But I want that transparent div to become pink if the text inside editbox is not number. How can I do this? I tried something like this but nothing works:

```
function proz(){
    var textbox = document.getElementById("nr").value; / nr is editbox
    var div = document.getElementById("proz"); / proz is the transparent div

    if (document.getElementById("nr").value == "a"){ / i tried with if var == "a" but nothing.
        div.setAtribute("id", "proz2"); /here proz 2 is another pink div, trying to overlay first div
    }
}
```

I am trying with only letter "a" instead of numbers to check if anything works at least...
So any advices please.
Thank you!

Later Edit:
HTML part:

```
<body>

<div class="patratpunctat">
<h1><center> Panou centrat </center></h1>
<p> Acest panou va fi centrat vertical si orizontal in pagina.</p>

    <div class="pportocaliu">
        <div class="prosualbastru"> </div>
    </div>
    <!-- -->
    <!-- partea pentru patratul roz cu javascript-->

    <div class="proz">

        <div class="inputt">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Numar interg" name="nrintreg">
        </div>

        <script>

        function check(){
            var textbox = document.getElementById("nrintreg").value;

            if (document.getElementById("nrintreg").value == "a"){
                window.alert('omg')
            }
        }

        </script>

    </div>
</div>


</body>
```

And yes, I am trying to make it instantly. Like if there is something else than a number there, to make the div pink. if it is Number, div remains transparent.

Comment: are you wanting to check this.. live? As in. The instant a user types in the box? Or check this after you click a button or on some other event? Also, could you post your html as well?

Comment: You need to add a change [event handler](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp) to the editbox (input, textarea?) and execute your code. Also, don't change the `id` because then when your code is executed again it will fail at `getElementById("proz")p`. Use a css class instead to format the element.

Comment: take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're going for?

```js
var textbox = document.getElementById("nr"); // nr is editbox
var div = document.getElementById("proz"); // proz is the transparent div

function proz() {
  div.style.backgroundColor = textbox.value
}

textbox.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
    proz();
});
```

```css
#proz {
  height:250px;
  width:250px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nr" />

<div id="proz"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a change [event handler](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp) to the editbox (input, textarea?) and execute your code.

Also, don't change the `id` because then when your code is executed again it will fail at `getElementById("proz")`. Use a css class instead to format the element.

Here you have a working version (the div will be pink when the value of the input text is `a`):

```js
var textbox = document.getElementById("nr");
var div = document.getElementById("proz");

textbox.onkeyup = proz;

function proz() {
    if (textbox.value == "a") {
        div.classList.add("pink");
    } else {
        div.classList.remove("pink");
    }
}
```

```css
#proz {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#proz.pink {
  background-color: #FF9999;
}
```

```html
<input id="nr" />
<div id="proz"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve but this was my interpretation of what you might want based on your question.This code checks if the input is a number. If it is, then it will do nothing. If it isn't a number, it will make the transparent div around the text box pink. Hope it helps in some way

```js
document.getElementById('nr').addEventListener("keyup", proz);
function proz(){
 var textbox = document.getElementById("nr").value; 
 var div = document.getElementById("proz"); 
 if (isNaN(textbox) == true){ 
  document.getElementById("some-div").style.background = "pink";
  }
  else
  {
  document.getElementById("some-div").style.background = ' transparent';
  }
}
```

```css
#some-div
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width:200px; 
height:200px; 
z-index:-1; 
}
```

```html
<div id = "some-div"> 
<input type="text" id='nr'><br>
  

</div>
```

Comment: I think `isNaN(6)` should be `isNaN(textbox)`.